# Loading saved records like addresses or postal records when return users checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know how to load a list of addresses or postal records when return users checkout.

From the front end, user just selects a dropdown record from history, and selects the specific address as a delivery address.

While for the backend - the database will able to capture as a new entry for delivery address, but the duplicated address / similar address will not shown from the dropdown menu.

Kind of newbie for `rails` and thanks.

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you provide more context? Do you mean like a database of postal addresses of the whole country/world?

Comment: @stwienert Sorry for the poor descriptions, basically I was intended to keep all the past transactions history and mailing addresses have made by every user. Once they check out from each transaction they can either select from the historical records like mailing address listing or enter a new address